# When does a system of inequalities have only the solution $x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ real valued matrix, $n\ge 2$. For every column n-vector $x$ from $A\cdot x=0$ we get $n$ equations

$$a_1^1x_1+a_1^2x_2+\dots+a_1^nx_n=0\\a_2^1x_1+a_2^2x_2+\dots+a_2^nx_n=0\\\dots\\a_n^1x_1+a_n^2x_2+\dots+a_n^nx_n=0$$

I know that if $det(A)\neq 0$ then the only solution to $A\cdot x=0$ is $x=0$.

Now replace all the previous equalities with inequalities in order to obtain the following system:

$$a_1^1x_1+a_1^2x_2+\dots+a_1^nx_n\ge 0\\a_2^1x_1+a_2^2x_2+\dots+a_2^nx_n\ge 0\\\dots\\a_n^1x_1+a_n^2x_2+\dots+a_n^nx_n\ge 0$$

**Which conditions on the matrix $A$ will guarantee that the only solution of this system of inequalities is $x=0$?**

Of course if $det(A)=0$ the condition can not be satisfied, so we'll suppose $det(A)\neq 0$ and search for additional conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have said, the left hand sides can be viewed as the action of a matrix on a vector ($A \vec x$).

If $A$ has full rank, then it is invertible, then your requirement cannot be met.

If $A$ does not have full rank, then its kernel is not trivial, then there would be other vectors being mapped to the zero vector, so your reuqirement cannot be met.

This means that it is impossible.

Comment: Thank you, I can't understand one point: if $A$ is invertible, then why is it impossible for my condition to be satisfied?

Comment: @user294185 If $A$ has an inverse, then its inverse must also be full-rank, meaning that non-zero elements maps to non-zero elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand why with these conditions there can't be an $x\neq 0$ such that $A\cdot x$ has all coordinates $\ge 0$ (for example which has $x_1>0$ and $x_i=0$, $i=2,\dots,n$)

Comment: @user294185 I think you misunderstood. There **can** be an $x\ne0$ such that $Ax$ has all coordinates $\ge0$, which is why it fails to meet your request. Your request is that there be **no other** $x$ satisfying that, and I pointed out that there **can** be other $x$.

Comment: ok, sorry, I understand now. But I'm still not convinced: $det(A)\neq 0$ is a necessary conditions for my requirement to be satisfied, but I don't think you proved that there can't be some additional conditions on $A$ which will guarantee that the system of inequalities has only the solution $x=0$

Comment: I also proved that it can't be satisfied if $\det(A)=0$. It is a true dichotomy. $\det A$ is either $=0$ or $\ne0$. I don't know what you mean by "some additional conditions".

Comment: yes it can not be satisfied if $det(A)=0$. So suppose $det(A)\neq 0$. Then there can be an $x\neq 0$ such that $A\cdot x$ has all coordinates $\ge 0$. My question is:which additional condition (apart from $det(A)\neq 0$) will guarantee that there can not be such $x\neq 0$?

Comment: @user294185 What I proved is that if $\det(A)\ne0$, then there **must** be a vector $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax$ has all coordinates $\ge 0$. You can't impose other conditions to falsify what I proved.

Comment: I'm sorry but then I don't understand your proof: are you saying that "non-zero elements map to non-zero elements" implies that there should be $x\neq 0$ such that $A\cdot x$ has all coordinates $\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Comment: but why is that?

Comment: Pick a non-zero vector with all coordinates $\ge 0$. Call it $\vec v$. Then, $A^{-1} \vec v$ is non-zero.